# Configuration of sectioning commands gives improperly nested xhtml in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
  \input{tex4ht.sty}
  \Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{subsection}{\HCode{<i>}}
    {\HCode{</i>}}
    {\HCode{<b>}}
    {\HCode{</b>}}
\begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
\subsection{One}
This is one
\subsection{Two}
This is two
\end{document}
```

In other words, the whole subsection should be wrapped in `<i>` tags and the heading in `<b>` tags.

Compiling with `ht latex test.tex` yields this between the `<body>` tags:

```html
<!--l. 10--><p class="indent" >   <i><b><a 
 id="x1-10000.0.1"></a>One</b> This is one
</p>
<!--l. 12--><p class="indent" >   </i><i><b><a 
 id="x1-20000.0.2"></a>Two</b> This is two </i></p>
```

Note that after `<!--l. 12-->`, the `<p class="indent" >` starts a new subsection **before** the previous subsection is closed with the `</i>` tag.  In my actual example, this is a `</idx:entry>` tag and the improper nesting throws an error.

Perhaps there is an explicit way to end the subsection that would flush the `</i>` tag before starting the `<p>` for the new subsection?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with `<p>` using some `tex4ht` internal commands. In this case, you need to:

1. close all paragraphs before section start at `<i>`
2. suppress `<p>` inside header
3. start new noindent paragraph after header
4. close paragraph before section end with `</i>`

So you can use this configuration:

```
  \Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{subsection}{\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{<i>}}
    {\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{</i>}}
    {\HCode{<b>}}
    {\HCode{</b>}\par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar}
\begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
```

`\EndP` close all `<p>` elements, `\IgnorePar` will suppress inserting paragraphs inside the header, after header end, we need to explicitly end paragraph with `\par`, `\IgnoreIndent` request next paragraph to be with no indent and `\ShowPar` will show starting `<p>` tag:

```html
 <i><b><a 
 id="x1-10000.0.1"></a>One</b>
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >This is one
</p>
   </i><i><b><a 
 id="x1-20000.0.2"></a>Two</b>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >This is two
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   Hello world
</p><!--l. 10--><p class="indent" >  another paragraph
</p>
   </i><i><b><a 
 id="x1-30000.0.3"></a>Three</b>
<!--l. 13--><p class="noindent" >This is three
</p><!--l. 15--><p class="indent" >  Hello, hello
</p>
   </i>
```

Comment: Thank you, @michal.h21.  After posting this, I managed to figure part of it out, but this helps to clarify it. I now understand that `\EndP` closes the *previous* paragraph, but the fact that you put the `\par` in *after* the header (presumably to close the *previous* paragraph), is not at all intuitive! Thanks, as always.

Comment: @NatKuhn I put `\par` to start a new paragraph, because it is not started automatically when there is no blank line between subsection and following text

Comment: @michal.h21 Is there a documentation about `tex4ht` internal commands? I found casual explanation for `Tg` and `HCode`, here you explain that `\par` means "start a new paragraph if not already started", but many other commands remain unclear.

Comment: @mmj `\par` is internal TeX command, it isn't provided by tex4ht. [There is documentation for basic configurations](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-infoch2.html#tex4ht-infose3.html), see especially `tex4ht` and `LaTeX` chapters. Basic documentation for commands [is here](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn11.html#QQ1-11-51), you can see sample usage when you click on numbered links before the commands.